# Django incremental change in simultaneous ModelForm submission

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

My model has a field **working_hour** which is **PositiveIntegerField**, I am using **ModelForm** and **django-crispy-forms**.Assume tow different people has rendered form with **working_hour** value **20** and both of them want to increase **working_hour** by **10** and they updates the working_hour form field from 20 to 30.When they both submit the form, updated working_hour becomes **30** in database, but it should be **40**.

models.py

```
class OverallHour(models.Model):

    working_hour = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

views.py

```
class OverallHourUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = OverallHour
    form_class = OverallHourForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

forms.py

```
class OverallHourForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OverallHour

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'UPDATE'))
```

overall_hour_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card bg-light">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {% crispy form %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I just need change delta from initial form value in the server when they submit the form.Can you please advice me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!

```
class OverallHourForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OverallHour

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'UPDATE'))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProjectForm, self).clean()
        print(self.has_changed())
        print(self.changed_data)
        print(self.initial)
        print(cleaned_data)
```